# How to assert the full response, not just the"view" part using Zend_Test_PHPUnit?

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit, zend-test

I want to test that my `/login` page is working well and rejecting invalid credentials i.e. not redirecting to the user's dashboard and showing an aller message identified here with the `.alert` HTML class. So I've created a test like this:

```
class AuthControllerTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase {
    ...
    public function testUserFailingLogin() {

        $this->request->setPost(array(
            'email'  => 'wrong@email.com',
            'password' => 'wrongpassword',
        ));

        $this->request->setMethod('POST');
        $this->dispatch('/login');

        $this->assertQuery('.alert');
    }
}
```

My problem is that the `assertQuery()` method is running against the render of `login.phtml` view file and is not including my Zend_Layout set up (that's where the `.alert`'s are shown) and thereof, the `assertQuery()` assertion fails always.

Is there any way to get `assert*Query*()` assertions evaluating the full response ("layout" + "view"), instead of just the "view" part?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You(I) should use the undocumented `outputBody()` method.